# Meaning of "definitively vanishing sequence" in universal tensor algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, mathematical-physics

I'm reading [arXiv: 1706.09666 [math-ph]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09666). In page 33 the authors introduce the universal tensor algebra for the vector space $\mathcal{E}^{obs}(M)$ through
$$\mathcal{T}^{obs}(M) = \mathbb{C} \otimes \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} (\mathcal{E}^{obs}(M))^{\otimes n},$$
where $(\mathcal{E}^{obs}(M))^{\otimes 0} = \mathbb{R}$. They then go to mention that

> [The elements of $\mathcal{T}^{obs}(M)$] are therefore *complex* linear combinations of the *definitively vanishing* sequences of real functions $F=(\phi^{(0)},\phi^{(1)},\ldots)$ with $\phi^{(k)} \in (\mathcal{E}^{obs}(M))^{\otimes k}$.

What does "definitively vanishing sequence" means in this context?